# Add AJAX to PHP Form

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I am making a website where you can random throw dices. 
First I made the function to throw in JavaScript. Now I want it in PHP.
Everything works, but the whole Site is always reloading if I try to throw it in PHP.

So I read I must use AJAX. But it doesen't work. The Site uses jQuery, so it should be an easy task. I tried it for hours but it doesen't work.
Can you see where the problem is?

The code is as following:

```html
<form name="imageForm">
<table border=0>
<tr>
<td>
<img src="<?php echo $randomImage; ?>" name="canvas" width="50%" height="auto"/>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
<br>
<form method="post"><input type="submit" name="random" id="randomImage" value="random" class="btn type--uppercase"/><br/></form>
<a onclick="displayImage();" class="btn btn--lg type--uppercase" href="#random"><span class="btn__text">
Random Dice Roll
</span>
</td>

</tr>
</table>
</form>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</section>

 
<!-- Scripts -->
<script>
function displayImage(){
$.ajax({
url: "random.php",
success: function(data){
$('img[name="canvas"]').attr('src', data);
}
});
return false;
}
</script>
<script src="js/parallax.js"></script>
<script src="js/smooth-scroll.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/scripts.js"></script>
<script src="js/random-dice-6-sides/random.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

And the random.php

```html
<?php
    $imagesDir = 'img/random-dice-6-sides/';
    $images = glob($imagesDir . '*.{jpg,jpeg,png,gif}', GLOB_BRACE);
    $randomImage = $images[array_rand($images)];
    echo $randomImage;
?>
```

You can see the whole process on https://randomster.com/random-dice-6-sides.php

The orange button is the php call, and the white is the Javascript call.

Thanks for your help!
Greetings

Comment: Don't obfuscate your question please.

Answer (score 1):

Since you have already attached an event handler `onclick="displayImage();"` with the anchor tag, your jQuery/AJAX code should be like this:

```
<script>
    function displayImage(){
        $.ajax({
            url: "YOUR_PAGE.php",
            success: function(data){
                $('img[name="canvas"]').attr('src', data);
            }
        });
        return false;
    }
</script>
```

*Don't forget to replace YOUR_PAGE.php with your actual page i.e. the page where you want to send the AJAX request.*

And in the backend PHP code, you just have to `echo` the `$randomImage`,

```
<?php
    $imagesDir = 'img/random-dice-6-sides/';
    $images = glob($imagesDir . '*.{jpg,jpeg,png,gif}', GLOB_BRACE);
    $randomImage = $images[array_rand($images)];
    echo $randomImage;
?>
```

Comment: Hey there! Thanks for your help. I added the code, but the same page is always reloading and I'm not sure why. And now the echo is shown at top of the page instead of the dice. I updated my original post with the complete source code. Can you review it and see the problem? Thank you so much!

Comment: @JohnNoe May be you should return `false` from `displayImage()` function to avoid reloading/redirection. I've updated my answer, please test your application with the updated code snippet.

Comment: @JohnNoe Ah, I can see now. You have to segregate your jQuery/AJAX code and backend PHP code i.e. put your PHP code in a different page and change the url setting, `url: "YOUR_PAGE.php",` in the AJAX request accordingly.

Comment: Hey there! I put the php code in random.php and included it. But no way, always the same error. I updated my question again. Its driving me crazy :/

Comment: @JohnNoe You didn't change the `url` setting of your AJAX request, change it to `url: "random.php",`

Comment: Hey! Now I did. But same result.

Comment: @JohnNoe 1. I still don't see `random.php` in the `url` setting of your AJAX request. 2. Post only the relevant code snippet(s) with your question. 3. Check whether the relative path of images are correct or not.

Comment: Hey there. No problem. I cut down the code and added the current state. The picture paths are correct.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest moving jquery script link to  as right now it's at the bottom of  and I get `ReferenceError: $ is not defined`.

A few changes were made. Your target file (which should return new image) I added:

```
<?php
$imagesDir = 'img/random-dice-6-sides/';
$images = glob($imagesDir . '*.{jpg,jpeg,png,gif}', GLOB_BRACE);
echo $images[array_rand($images)];
```

And your index file:

```
<?php
$imagesDir = 'img/random-dice-6-sides/';
$images = glob($imagesDir . '*.{jpg,jpeg,png,gif}', GLOB_BRACE);
$randomImage = $images[array_rand($images)];
// Display initial image
?>

<section class="text-center page-title bg--dark">
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-10 col-lg-8">
<h1>Welcome to Randomster.com</h1>
<p class="lead"> Blah </p>
<form name="imageForm">
<table border=0>
<tr>
<td>
<!-- Result displayed here -->
<img id="canvas" src="<?php echo $randomImage; ?>" name="canvas" width="50%" height="auto"/>                                                        </td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
<br>
<!--PHP Call-->
<form method="post">
    <input type="submit" name="random" id="randomImage" value="random" class="btn type--uppercase"/><br/>
</form>
<!--Javascript Call-->
<a onclick="displayImage();" class="btn btn--lg type--uppercase" href="#random"><span class="btn__text">Random Dice Roll
</span>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</section>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    // AJAX to target file (in this case, index2.php)
    $("#randomImage").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        $.ajax({
            method: "POST",
            url: "index2.php",
        })
        .done(function(results) {
            $("#canvas").attr('src', results);
        })
    });
});
</script>
```

The PHP part to show initial image. The image element has an ID now because jQuery needs it (in my case) and AJAX was added.

Comment: Hey there! Thanks for your help. I added the code, but the same page is always reloading and I'm not sure why. And now the echo is shown at top of the page instead of the dice. I updated my original post with the complete source code. Can you review it and see the problem? Thank you so much!

Comment: @JohnNoe True. Updated. You need to stop event from using default action. Check for `e.preventDefault();`.